# How to check an environment is section or chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

How to check an environment is section or chapter? I tried `\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne (or \z@) do something for sections \else chapter\fi` but it has no effect.

I want to place a book and a paper icon before chapter and section title in `toc` respectively. (for this question consider, book icon:=`\spadesuit` and paper icon:=`\S`). The first and easy solution is to redefine `\numberline` as follow:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
 renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \S \else $\spadesuit$\fi~#1~}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{title}\chapter{title}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-50]

\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{title}\chapter{title}
\setcounter{section}{99}
\section{Yet another section}
\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{title}\chapter{title}
\setcounter{section}{999}
\section{Last section}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there are no environments in your example other than `document`. I think you mean "command" not "environment" ?  Also there is no need to test for this simply specify the prefix as part of the table of contents layout which is defined individually for each heading command (`\l@chapter`, `\l@section`...)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But inside heading command (`\l@chapter` ,` \l@section` ...)  there is nothing except `\@dottedtocline{<level>}{<indent>}{<numwidth>}`!!!

Comment: The `book` version of `\chapter` doesn't use `\@dottedtocline` at all. `\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tocloft` package (`> texdoc tocloft` to see the documentation).

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand*{\cftchappresnum}{\spadesuit} % put before chapter number in ToC
\renewcommand*{\cftsecpresnum}{\S} % put before section number in ToC
```

You might also need to increase the space available for the enhanced numbers, like

```
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{<your length>}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{<your length>}
```